# Sort a data frame by name and then by date while keeping the name sorting

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below:

```
    product<-c("asd","saf","asd","bc","asd","saf","bc","saf")
date<-as.Date(c("2018-07-29","2018-07-25","2018-07-28","2018-06-29","2018-07-21","2018-07-12","2018-02-28","2018-07-10"))
p<-data.frame(product,date)
```

What I want to achieve is sort this dataframe by product name firstly and then by date without ruining the initial sorting.

I use:

```
p <- p %>% arrange(product)
```

to sort by name but when I use:

```
p<-p[order(as.Date(p$date, format="%Y/%m/%d")),]
```

the name sorting is lost.

An acceptable solution would be:

```
product       date
1     asd 2018-07-25
2     asd 2018-07-28
3     asd 2018-07-29
4     saf 2018-02-28
5     saf 2018-06-29
6     saf 2018-07-10
7      bc 2018-02-28
8      bc 2018-07-12
```

as I do not care about alphabetical sorting between names.

Comment: If you are looking to sort product then product `bc` should be before to `saf`

Comment: I dont care about alphabetical order I just want all the same products to be all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select * from p order by product,date")
```

Output:

```
  product       date
1     asd 2018-07-21
2     asd 2018-07-28
3     asd 2018-07-29
4      bc 2018-02-28
5      bc 2018-06-29
6     saf 2018-07-10
7     saf 2018-07-12
8     saf 2018-07-25
```

Comment: @firmo23: Please let me know in case I am following the wrong direction.

Comment: great answer thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Basically ordering taking into account both columns:

```
p[order(p$product,p$date),]
```

Output:

```
  product       date
5     asd 2018-07-21
3     asd 2018-07-28
1     asd 2018-07-29
7      bc 2018-02-28
4      bc 2018-06-29
8     saf 2018-07-10
6     saf 2018-07-12
2     saf 2018-07-25
```

I believe this question is already repeated. Indeed, just in case I put it here, it has much more information:
[How to sort a dataframe by multiple column(s)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-multiple-columns)